# Changing the default keyboard language in the search input of a ListView

Tags: java, android, keyboard

I've added a simple input search function to a listview:

```
inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            MainActivity.this.mAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        }
    });
```

I use other language (not english) in the names of listview items. But when I try to search some name, there is only english keybord presented. It does not have change language function. Even set default keybord (with my language) in android settings does not help. How can I set keyboard with my language as a default in input search?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK,
Only system apps can change the keyboard language not the ones which are installed from external sources.

If you want to change the keyboard layout for your app, you need to write your own customised keyboard layout.